# How do I use Android PowerProfile private API?

Tags: android

I downloaded the source code from the below link and added to my project.

http://grepcode.com/file/repository.grepcode.com/java/ext/com.google.android/android/2.2_r1.1/com/android/internal/os/PowerProfile.java

I am getting and it can not find R file shown below.

```
 int id = com.android.internal.R.xml.power_profile;
```

Also can not import

```
import com.android.internal.util.XmlUtils;
```

I basically want to measure the power consumption of Android devices.

Comment: If it is not part of the public APIs then it is likely either not going to work, or be very difficult. And even if you manage to get it working it is likely whatever means you use to make it work will get broken at some point by an OS update.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can access the internal API that is `com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile`

just take a look at [this link](https://devmaze.wordpress.com/2011/01/19/using-com-android-internal-part-5-summary-and-example), and follow the step by step process.

Answer (score 3):

Personally using patached android.jar just causes headaches, using reflection is a 'simple' way of accessing PowerProfile.java. But as @FoamyGuy and countless others have noted this is hidden api so wrap it in a big try catch as it could break on later version of Android.

```
Class<?> powerProfileClazz = Class.forName("com.android.internal.os.PowerProfile");

//get constructor that takes a context object
Class[] argTypes = { Context.class };
Constructor constructor = powerProfileClazz
            .getDeclaredConstructor(argTypes);
Object[] arguments = { context };
//Instantiate
Object powerProInstance = constructor.newInstance(arguments);

//define method
Method batteryCap = powerProfileClazz.getMethod("getBatteryCapacity", null);

//call method 
Log.d(TAG, batteryCap.invoke(powerProInstance, null).toString());
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use

```
int id = Resources.getSystem().getIdentifier("power_profile", "xml", "android");
```

But be aware of what FoamyGuy commented.

Answer (score 1):

Easiest way to do this is to download the framework.jar of android and include that as external library in your project. After including the framework.jar in your android project you can find that resource file.